# Command is started more than once in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sh, ash

I'm trying to start one tcpdump in with my script. But I always get more than one. That's my ps output:

```
 1260 root     tcpdump -i br0 -C 1024 -w /media/usbhd-sdc2/pcaps/abfrage2.pcap
 1267 root     tcpdump -i br0 -C 1024 -w /media/usbhd-sdc2/pcaps/abfrage2.pcap
```

That's my code where I check if the uptime is the same like my start-time.
If it's the same, it should start a tcpdump and it should also save the PID.
But why does it start a second one, does this happen, because my function readPID isn't fast enough?

```
 if [[ $timestart == $Zeit ]] || [[ "$pid1" != "" ]];then
                echo "First"
                if [[ $timeend != $Zeit ]];then
                        echo "second"
                        if [ "$pid1" == "" ];then
                                echo "third"
                                if [ "$port" != "" ];then
                                        echo "fourth"
                                        run_tcpdump port
                                        pid1=$(readPID1)
                                        echo $pid1
                                else
```

ReadPID funtion:

```
readPID1(){
ps -eo pid,args|awk '/abfrage2/ && ! /awk/{print $1}'
}
```

**Update**

Tcpdump function:

```
run_tcpdump(){
if [ "$1" == "port" ];then
  sudo tcpdump port $port -i br0 -C 1024 -w /media/usbhd-sd[b-c]2/pcaps/abfrage2.pcap &
else
  sudo tcpdump -i br0 -C 1024 -w /media/usbhd-sd[b-c]2/pcaps/abfrage2.pcap &
fi
}
```

Comment: Naming a shell function after a utility (which you also run) strikes me as just *begging* for surprises...

Comment: @Jens Changed the name of the function, actually didn't thought of that, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I can guess again that you may have another call of this function somewhere. Or called this script twice.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you might call your `tcpdump` function instead of system-wide package. rename it in your script to `run_tcpdump` for example. Not sure it is the root cause though.

Also make sure you have no `tcpdump` processes before you've started your script. Are you sure first process was not from previous run?

Comment: So I changed the name to run_tcpdump, still doesn't work.